# Stuck in a login loop but Lets me only access cinnamon (SOLVED)

Tags: 23.10

How do i fix the Login Loop from ubuntu mantic?
I installed the Plasma X11 to try it out
then ubuntu desktop wasnt working correctly.
i was thinking that Plasma killed ubuntu.
so I uninstalled to fix the problem.
I installed cinnamon after
but i still cant figure out how to fix the ubuntu desktop not working because of Plasma X11.
it kept on doing the loop login thing but it only lets me run cinnamon. it still lets me run GNOME apps. but how do i fix ubuntu desktop and gnome classic?

Apparently. my problem was that Wayland was Removed.

Comment: Please let us know which all desktop interfaces you installed or uninstalled, and if you installed any display managers (like SDDM/GDM/lightDM). Otherwise, we really don't know what is going on with your system.

Comment: I agree with @ArchismanPanigrahi  as the changes you made are unclear (ie. no package details; you mention uninstalling but weren't specific as to what exactly you removed and if you purged etc). In your position I'd likely explore your *apt* logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) and ensure nothing required was removed in error, otherwise config details are where I'd look (*but you mention uninstall & not if you purged; details matter*)...

Comment: Desktop Environments are GNOME Classic, Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Xorg, Cinnamon, Cinnamon (Software Rendering). These are the Desktop Environments that show up on my desktop environment list. I tried Reinstalling the ubuntu desktop. it didnt work. i also did $ reboot after. From now on. it only lets me go on cinnamon desktop.

Comment: So. You tried getting ubuntu back by reinstalling the desktop back?
This login loop is very common to people. but i dont know how you login to cinnamon. Did you try following this article https://tinyurl.com/mryt2c6b ? I followed it. and it helped me. so i believe it could help you.

Comment: This didnt work. i tried all the steps. Ubuntu was installed through a usb. so i believe some stuff may not work as the preinstalled one i tried the article. did all the steps, even checked disk usage, and did the if all fails on the link. any other solutions?

Comment: I presume the login screen shows.  But the login loop occurs after you enter your username and password?  If so, try dropping to a shell and create a new account.  Then log in with that new account.  If that account works, then there's a problem with your first account's local configuration files.